# Why is a switch port a collision domain?

Tags: cisco, switch, network, duplex

I'm just starting my IT education and this is probably a very basic question but I'm having trouble with it.
As far as I understand a collision domain is a part of a network where collisions can occur.
Let's say we have two PCs connected to a switch and nothing else.
Why is each port considered a collision domain when there's no collisions that can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collision domain is created by a port running in half-duplex mode (due to requiring media arbitration using CSMA/CD). The collison domain spans all ports within the same layer-1 segment - it crosses repeaters (hubs) but ends at host, switch or router ports.

Half-duplex and CSMA/CD are all but obsolete. Practically, they only existed for 10 and 100 Mbit/s Ethernet. Gigabit and faster speeds use full-duplex transmission throughout. With full duplex there's no media arbitration and therefore no collision domain anywhere.

Comment: I see, so in my example there actually wouldn't be any collision domain, if all ports run full-duplex?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If each host and the switch support full-duplex mode (a given for all devices from this century), that mode is auto negotiated and used. Even if half-duplex mode was used, each switch port creates a collision domain of its own. Of course, each switch port can run in half or in full duplex, independent from each other.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you connect on this port a hub (yes they are increasingly rare but still exists)

Now you have a real collision domain on your port.

You are right that in practice this is less and less a concern, but still the principle remains.

Also the fact is most network courses are vastly outdated (if your course talk about classful network - class A, B, C etc.. it is totally outdated)

Comment: So basically it's only a collision domain because a half duplex device COULD be connected to it?
Apparently this is part of the CCNA cert, so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @KaranVess That answer isn't quite correct as a collision domain could very well span just two ports, the switch port and the host port, when both are operating in *half-duplex mode*.